# C++ classes getting value using pointers and strcpy

Tags: c++, class, pointers, strcpy

I am trying to understand C++. Can anybody explain what this code does exactly, I understood that it is some type of setter and getter in Java but I am not sure.

```
Comm::Comm(const char* id)
{
strcpy(this->id, id);
}


char* Comm::getId()
{
   return id;
}
```

Comment: Plain bad code (if your example shows all)

Comment: It's not a setter it's a constructor

Comment: I strongly recommend for you to get some book that will teach your C++ grounds up. I must say that "Beginning C++ through game programming" is not half bad.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be better suited to a chatroom, or a discussion forum, or a one-on-one mentoring session.

Comment: @user3126119: How do you do what?

Comment: It unsafely copies a null-terminated string to what I can only assume is an array of characters in the class `Comm`. Since there is no bounds checking / truncation, this is terrible. `strncpy (...)` would make me cringe a lot less.

Answer (score 7):

What does this code do?

**It burns the eyes of children.**

The assumption here is that the class `Comm` has a member variable of type `char*` or `char[N]`. There is no "setter" *per se*, but `Comm`'s constructor attempts to copy its input to that member variable. The `getId` function is a getter for this member variable.

Depending on the rest of the code, this could be totally flawed due to lack of memory allocation, lack of memory de-allocation, and lack of copy semantics. At *best* the member is an array and then the lack of range checking in the `strcpy` call is a serious security risk.

The class would be much better redesigned with the use of `std::string`.

**I would *not* encourage you to learn from this code snippet.**

Instead, learn from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648).

Comment: This answer is useless, too

Comment: @DieterLücking: Thanks for your mature and productive contribution.

Comment: Thanks for your well informed 'It burns the eyes of children'

Comment: @DieterLücking: You know, I _did_ write other words...

Comment: How helpful is 'I would not encourage you to learn from this code snippet' ?

Comment: @DieterLücking: How is it _not_ helpful? The OP may not be aware that this is potentially very poor code. How does telling him about this not help? I am sharing my expertise for free. That is helpful. Your whining on my answer without giving any constructive criticism _whatsoever_ is _not_ helpful. Please cease, and feel free to write your own answer if you think you can do so much better!