# C++ Constructor setting value

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to write a constructor in C++ (I am new).

My Attempt:

```
class Tree
{
    private:
        int leaf;

    public:
        Tree(int leaf); //constructor
};

Tree::Tree(int leaf) //constructor
{
strcpy(this->leaf, leaf);
}
```

Is this the proper way how to do it? Since I found many different version with srcpy, without , etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing fields in constructor - initializer list vs constructor body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903248/initializing-fields-in-constructor-initializer-list-vs-constructor-body)

Comment: Would you kindly do us a favour and help us understand how people learn C++ -- please explain *why* did you feel that `strcpy` was appropriate here? I'm genuinely curious about the thought process.

Comment: I'm sorry to see that you did not read [my answer on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20939216/560648), or Google `strcpy` to find out what it does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "What does this code do? It burns the eyes of children." Hahaha

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not. `strcpy` is for copying null-terminated strings. Use the constructor initialization list:

```
Tree::Tree(int leaf) : leaf(leaf) {}
```

Also note that your constructor allows for implicit conversions from `int` to `Tree`. So you can do this kind of thing:

```
Tree t = 4 + 5;
```

If you do not want this behaviour, mark the constructor explicit:

```
explicit Tree(int leaf);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply initialize the int like this:

```
Tree::Tree(int leaf) //constructor
  : leaf(leaf)
{
}
```

`strcpy` is not needed, it is meant for C-strings. It does not compile since it expects a `char*` pointer.

Comment: so if you use a string (char* ) you have to use strcpy then?

Comment: @user3126119, I suggest using a `std::string` and doing the exact same thing as this. @cage, It initializes it, not assigns.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use C-strings (char*). Use C++ strings  (`std::string`) which can be initialized like your `int`.

Comment: @cageman it's initialization, not assignment. Also, `strcpy` [won't compile](http://ideone.com/teActm) here, fixed that in your answer.

Comment: can you edit my code with std::string since I cannot figure how to do it I have been trying and still no success. I would appreciate a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::copy` if you *really* want to use some sort of memory-copying function, but `m_leaf = leaf` works just as well and is easier to read.  Notice my use of `m_leaf` instead of `leaf` - it's common to add the prefix `m_` before all member variables (More on Hungarian Notation [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HungarianNotation)).